# How do you differentiate relative and absolute shape keys?

Tags: animation, shape-keys

My question regards the difference of relative and absolute shape keys.

As it stands, relative keys are great for easy shapes and are measured on 0-1.
Absolute keys are measured in frames and are used for deforming mesh in more complex ways than relative keys. If you want to use relative and absolute shape keys in the model, it has been suggested to use **mask modifier** and two overlapping shapes to differentiate the shape keys. This leaves a definite sharp line on the edge of masked parts.

Has anyone seen any examples or videos where someone has used the absolute keys?

I'm interested in this topic, but have not found any material so far in the internet.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Relative Shape keys:**

*With absolute shape keys, the value shown for each shape in the list represents the current weight or influence of that shape in the current Mix.*

**Absolute Shape Keys:**

With absolute shape keys, the value shown for each shape in the list represents the Evaluation Time at which that shape key will be active.

[image]

Comment: Could you simplify and show some example about absolute shape keys?

Comment: For example, if you have the shape keys, Basis, Key_1, Key_2, in that order.Evaluation Time will show this as frame 100:

Basis 10.0
Key_1 20.0
Key_2 30.0     Maybe it will help u bud..

Comment: Unfortunsately it did not.